# "@@" in patch/diff (linux)?

Tags: linux, diff, patch

I'm really new to linux patches and diff.  I'm trying to edit a patch and there's some errors and I have to fix them.

I've come across:
@@ -11,7 +11,6 @@

many times in the patch (diff) file and I think the first set of numbers represent the starting line number and number of lines to be edited, but what does the second set represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the resultant starting line and the number of lines in the resultant chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that editing a diff is very fragile.  If you change the number of lines anywhere in any chunk, you'll break the diff unless you also update the chunks and line numbers.